# Finding InstallShield Services/Processes

Tags: installshield

Is there a possible way to figure out what services or processes InstallShield is currently using? I'm trying to end all of the services/processes relating to InstallShield. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A good tool for inspecting/killing/identifying processes is Process Explorer, available fro free:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

You can use it to identify the processes and also, see the resources used by the process.